How to align two figures on the right side of boxes within a tabItem page in a shinydashboard app
I have the following tabItem page within my shinydashboard app:
tabItem(
      tabName = "info",
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 9,
          style = "padding:0px;",
          box(
            width = 9,
            title = h2(strong("Header1")),
            text1
          ),
          box(
            width = 9,
            title = h2(strong("Header2")),
            text2
          ),
          box(
            width = 9,
            title = h2(strong("Header3")),
            text3
          )
        ),
        column(
          width = 3,
          style = 'padding:0px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; height: 100%; align-items: center;',
          align = "center",
          div(
            style = "margin-bottom: 50px;",
            img(src ='fig1.png', width = "100%")
          ),
          div(
            style = "margin-bottom: 50px;",
            img(src ='fig2.png', width = "100%")
          )
        )
      )
    )

This will generate a page where the three boxes with text aligns on top of one another on the left side, and the two figures on the right. However, The two figures does not align to the center of the remaining space, and gets clustered on the top right. How do I get them to align in the center? Something like this:


Share a minimal reproducible example of your app. That is the way to get help here.
